# Minecraft server crash?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I had a problem with java saying something about ram, then windows saying to stop minecraft because it will run out of memory. Now I'm unsure what to do. Whenever i start my server (bungee) I get this: https://gyazo.com/6aab5227c9329fe386162ba9d05e3f32

Comment: You seam to be low on RAM. Restart your PC, then DON'T open any browsers, try starting the server. Also do you have enough hard drive space ?

Comment: "PLS READ!". Please avoid titles like these. Be descriptive.

Comment: Please avoid taking screenshots of logs, please copy and paste them to either [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or put them in a code block or spoiler.

Comment: The crash report shows that there are plugins enabled on the server. Therefore, this question is off topic as tech support for modded minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because support for modded minecraft is not allowed here.

Comment: It's actually a minecraft *server*, not a client mod.

Comment: I've posted a [Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13467/modded-minecraft-server-tech-support) about modded servers. Feel free to post your two cents.

Answer (score 2):

You allocated more RAM to the software than you have.

Visit [this WikiHow page](https://www.wikihow.com/Check-Computer-RAM) and determine how much RAM you have, the simply change the `-Xmx` parameter to your liking. You should allocate at least 1/4th of your RAM to your server and increase this if you add more plugins or players. **You should never allocate all your RAM**

Note: RAM and memory are the same thing.

Comment: Never allocate all your RAM, that will cause a lot of problems to your system. Minecraft isn't the only thing that needs RAM, your PC needs the RAM most. I suggested an edit.